# Android Spinner to give text answer displayed

Tags: android, text, spinner

I currently have a spinner giving the same result as the spinner selection. For example if I selected the word "Blue" from the spinner drop down the word "Blue" would be displayed in a text box below the spinner.

How would I go about displaying a different text result than the spinner selection name. For example, if I select "Blue" from the spinner I get a different paragraph of text shown below in the text box, which corresponds to my selection?

Any help would be appreciated as I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a listener on your spinner. Here is an example:

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            String s = (String) mySpinner.getSelectedItem();
            if (s.equals("Blue")){
                 myTextView.setText("GIANT PARAGRAPH");
            }//else ifs and so on...
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well all you need to do is set a conditional statement. Right now you're saying if blue is selected set the text for (yourtextviewname) to "blue". All you have to do is instead say, if blue is selected set the text to "whatever you want". Here is an example. This is not exact code, just an example of what you might want to try.

```
if (spinner.equals("blue")) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    tv.setText("Whatever I want to type!");
}
```

You can also set the `TextView` by a `String` resource. the only difference is you would put

```
 tv.setText(R.string.something);
```